# How to forward traffic for 80 and 443 ports from one server to another (Linux)

Tags: proxy

I would like to forward all traffic from server-A port 80 to server-B port 80 (OS is Linux). And the same for port 443. I know how to do it using nginx. But I want to do the same, but with iptables only (or with another netfilter tool).

The goal is to do quick setup of a proxy server-A without re-setupping of http/https configs from server-B.

The scheme is:

- Request: Client -> Server-A -> Server-B
- Response: Client <- Server-A <- Server-B
- I.e. Client interacts with Server-A only (actually with Server-B)
- Client must see IP address of Server-A only

I see it like some "fake" port listener, that immediately transfer all packets to a target server, and then transfer response from it back to the client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

First make sure `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1'` is set.

```bash
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to Server-B-IP:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d Server-B-IP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to Server-B-IP:443
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d Server-B-IP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d Server-B-IP --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source Server-A-IP
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d Server-B-IP --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source Server-A-IP
```

Now traffics on port 80,443 on Server-A will be forwarded to Server-B and response from Server-B will go to Server-A then back to client.

This works, however Server-B will always see requesting IP as Server-A.
You will not be able to get the real client ip on Server-B.

Comment: Questions about iptables, networking are off topic on SO. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  Do not answer off topic questions. Vote to close instead. [answer]